# Localization between Browser and Windows in Xpage

Tags: xpages, date-formatting

Short question: when localization on Browser and Windows is different
for example browser (English language date format: mm-dd-yyyy), Windows (Ukranian language date format: dd-mm-yyyy) I can`t create document with data.

I think it is throw Date format.
Error and stack trace are shown below.

Longer question (more open): I have page where I create and save Task, when I use Google Chrome (Ukranian language format date in this zone: dd-mm-yyyy) I make create and save Task but when I use Google Chrome (English language format date in this zone: mm-dd-yyyy) I create task after I go to check querySave event and see what log is write when I create task and I have page with url, then when I click on this url I have "Could not open the document"

And Stack Trace:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Could not open the document
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doOpenDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:509)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.openDocument(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:148)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.load(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:100)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.getDataContainer(AbstractDataSource.java:474)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getDataObject(DominoDocumentData.java:145)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.pushData(AbstractDataSource.java:576)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.DataPublisher.publishControlData(DataPublisher.java:181)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.publishControlData(UIDataPanelBase.java:310)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.initBeforeContents(UIDataPanelBase.java:451)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.initBeforePageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:668)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:339)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildFacet(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:205)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UICallback.buildContents(UICallback.java:180)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.buildContents(UIDataPanelBase.java:459)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildPageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:692)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:340)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:345)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:345)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.buildContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1649)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2.buildContents(UIViewRootEx2.java:247)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(AbstractCompiledPage.java:167)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:521)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:251)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
NotesException: Invalid universal id
    lotus.domino.local.Database.NgetDocumentByUNID(Native Method)
    lotus.domino.local.Database.getDocumentByUNID(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils.getDocumentById(DominoUtils.java:456)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils.getDocumentById(DominoUtils.java:477)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doOpenDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:489)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.openDocument(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:148)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.load(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:100)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.getDataContainer(AbstractDataSource.java:474)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getDataObject(DominoDocumentData.java:145)
    com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.pushData(AbstractDataSource.java:576)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.DataPublisher.publishControlData(DataPublisher.java:181)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.publishControlData(UIDataPanelBase.java:310)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.initBeforeContents(UIDataPanelBase.java:451)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.initBeforePageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:668)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:339)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildFacet(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:205)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UICallback.buildContents(UICallback.java:180)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.buildContents(UIDataPanelBase.java:459)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildPageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:692)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:340)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:345)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:345)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.buildContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1649)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2.buildContents(UIViewRootEx2.java:247)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(AbstractCompiledPage.java:167)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:521)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:251)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with your URL: NotesException: Invalid universal id. How do you build your URL?

Comment: Hi, example URL : "name_site/MySite.nsf/tasks.xsp?documentId=ED97AA6B86D8859FC22582BF003CAE35&action=openDocument&content=tasks_form"

Comment: Please post the dominoDocument datasource settings. These could be the problem.